# Vertica, describe table

Tags: python, vertica

I have a vertica database and I need to describe some tables. In MySQL you use `describe table_name`. And I know that in vertica it's `\d table_name`.
Also I need to do it throw python, but when I make query:

```
cur.execute("\d table_name")
```

I get this problem:

```
vertica_python.errors.VerticaSyntaxError: Severity: ERROR, Message: Syntax error at or near "\", Sqlstate: 42601, Position: 1, Routine: base_yyerror, File: /scratch_a/release/vbuild/vertica/Parser/scan.l, Line: 1004, SQL: '\\d table_name'
```

Is there another way to get columns and columns type in vertica?

Comment: `cur.execute(r'\d table_name')`? https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: Tried different ways. For example in this case: vertica_python.errors.VerticaSyntaxError: Severity: ERROR, Message: Syntax error at or near "\", Sqlstate: 42601, Position: 1, Routine: base_yyerror, File: /scratch_a/release/vbuild/vertica/Parser/scan.l, Line: 1004, SQL: '\\d table_name'

Comment: Found answer, if you want get columns and types, you can use: select * from COLUMNS where table_name = 'table_name'. You can select by table_schema and other params. My first meeting with vertica, think it will be fun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why your query fails:

The `\d` command is a specificity of vsql, this is not valid SQL you can use use via ODBC or JDBC for instance.

You have 3 options. First the one you already put in comment:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   v_catalog.columns 
WHERE  table_schema='schema' 
       AND table_name='table' 
ORDER  BY ordinal_position;`
```

The second option is to [export the object](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/EXPORT_OBJECTS.htm), which will give you the full create statement, including projections:

```
SELECT export_objects('', 'schema.table');
```

The third option is to [export the table](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/EXPORT_TABLES.htm), which only provides the table definition:

```
SELECT EXPORT_TABLES('', 'schema.table');
```

The first set of double quotes says to print the output on STDOUT, the second is the table (or schema or all the objects) you want to export.

Comment: NOTE: it seems an `S` need to be added to `TABLE` in the third option, `EXPORT_TABLES`

Answer (score 0):

There are [many ways to describe tables in vertica](https://www.orahow.com/2018/07/describe-table-in-vertica.html) but easiest is like this:

```
\d table_name;
\dt tablw_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **\d**  or get it using below dictionary table

```
select column_name, table_name
from v_catalog.columns
where column_name ilike '<column_name>'
and table_schema ilike '<table_name>'
order by column_name;
```

you can also add more attributes based on the required information that you need.